# Kotlin Flow with time out result

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to use Flow inside a CoroutineWorker(WorkManager) and the flow should be listening for a value in the repository for 5 seconds, if you get the value within that time frame you return Result.success() and then ignore/cancel the timer, if the time passed you return Result.failure()

right now I have something like that and I'm trying to incorporate the timeout there.

```
 repository.getListeningValue.onEach {
     //doStuff here with the result
 }.map{
     Result.success()
 }.first()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
withTimeoutOrNull(5_000) {
    flow.first()
    Result.success()
} ?: Result.failure()
```

I haven't tried it myself, but I think it should work.